# Relating Solutions to Accounts in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, soql

Hi I am new to Salesforce SOQL. I am trying to relate a solution to the accounts but can't get it working. I have created a query but calling from API and executing following query returns me a 'Case' object

```
   SELECT case.account.name 
   FROM case 
   WHERE id IN (
                  SELECT CaseId 
                  FROM CaseSolution 
                  WHERE SolutionId ='XXXXXXX'
               )
```

Comment: How do you call the query from API?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what data you want to have returned ? You're querying "FROM case" in your primary query, that will result in a list of case objects ..

Comment: @Sdry - I want all the all the name of the accounts that are associated with a solution.
Solution is linked to Case; Case is linked to Account. So the above mentioned query do return what I want but when calling from API since I have 'Case' in FROM clause so it isn't returning what I am expecting. Running same query in developer console in Salesforce returns exactly what I look for.

Answer (score 0):

What about querying the CaseSolution object and then Account Name details from the Case:

```
SELECT Case.Account.Name FROM CaseSolution WHERE SolutionId = 'XXXXXX' GROUP BY Case.Account.Name
```